# Can't find my assets folder

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I want to add a custom font. I read about the epic assets folder and her location over some themes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio). I check my src folder - it's not there. I check almost every single directory from my project tree and I still can't find her. Here is the picture of my directory tree.
And by the way, on my previous project, on Android 0.6 I used to add a custom font but I don't remember where was the folder located and now, on Android Studio 0.8 I even can't find my folder.
[image]

Comment: Did you try just adding it yourself?  Just put it in the `main` folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under your main folder you need to make an assets directory.

**Right click on the "main" folder -> New -> Directory**

And then name it "assets" and here is what it should now look like (minus the xml file of course)

[image: Asset folder]

Comment: Okay @DoubleElite. I just did it - it works completely fine. Thank you some much.

Comment: @StanimirYakimov no problem glad it worked :) If its the right answer feel free to tick the green arrow so everyone else can find it later.

Comment: there was some assets folder in res and i was getting error when accessing resources. This fixed everything. I think studio does not creates the assets folder in correct location....@DoubleElite thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Todays IDEs do most of the work for you. But if they fail, why you not just try to do it yourself? Place your assets-folder in `src\main\assets` and you should be fine.